# Italics in Formal Essays

Tags: writing

I want to say this quote in my essay:
"Jefferson is in every view less dangerous than Burr". I want to emphasize the word "every", so can I italicize it?

Answer (score 3):

Italicization is the conventional typographical method of emphasis. Before the advent of word processors a manuscript would use underscoring.

However, since you are quoting someone else's text in which this word is not emphasized, you must as a matter of sound scholarly practice make that clear—conventionally, by placing "[emphasis mine]", in brackets, after the quotation.

Comment: Any other alternative?

Comment: Alternatives? If we were still living in the pre-computer era, you could underline it. Now that we're in the post-computer era, you could put it in a blinking red font. But in both cases, you'd still have to put "[emphasis mine]" after the quote. And neither of these alternatives is at all a good idea.

Comment: @PeterShor Setting certain words in italic amidst a sea of otherwise unremarkable roman antedates the invention of the computer by many centuries.

Comment: @tchrist: For printers, yes. But ordinary people could only do it using relatively expensive typewriters.